# What is the correct way to do an async action using redux observable and firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

so I have this epic

```
export const listenToCountryVisitsEpic = (action$, store) => {
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType('UPDATE_TRIP_DETAILS'),
        mergeMap((action) => {
            const userId = store.value.user.id
            const { country, newDetails } = action
            const { people, places } = details
            const scheme = {
                people,
                places,
            }

            firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}/path`).update(scheme)

            return mergeMap((response) => {
                const payload = { ...JSON.parse(response.request.body), currentDetails: action.currentDetails }
                return [updatedCountrySuccess(payload)]
            })
        }),
    )
}
```

what I want to do is make the request to firebase and then if successful update redux which in turn will update react. if not successful then catch it

this is correctly posting to firebase but I need to catch errors correctly. I don't want to fire this: `updatedCountrySuccess` until I know it's a success or failure in firebase

can I use async/await for this?

Comment: If `update()` returns a Promise you can use async/await. You can also make it part of the RxJS chain.

Comment: @martin hi. im not sure if it does, gonna check the docs. if it doesn't can I not wrap it in a `return new Promise`?

Comment: martin yes it does return a promise. how would that look then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from()` to turn Promise into Observable and then `catchError` to replace the error with whatever you want.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

return action$.pipe(
    ofType('UPDATE_TRIP_DETAILS'),
    mergeMap((action) => {
        const userId = store.value.user.id
        const { country, newDetails } = action
        const { people, places } = details
        const scheme = {
            people,
            places,
        }

        return from(firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}/path`).update(scheme))
            .pipe(
                // `mergeMap` will handle only `next` notifications
                mergeMap((response) => {
                    const payload = ...
                    return [updatedCountrySuccess(payload)]
                }),
                catchError(error => of(errorAction)),
            );
    }),
)
```

Comment: thanks for this, looks really promising. just wondering why `response` in mergeMap is undefined tho?

Comment: You have to import it too from `rxjs/operators`

Comment: but isn't it passed as argument from `mergeMap` ?